# introductory real analysis - convergence and series Q

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Show that $\forall \epsilon > 0 $$ \exists H \in \mathbb{R} $ s.t. P>H & N>H implies $\left|1 - \displaystyle\sum_{p=2}^P\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^p \right| < \epsilon $

my attempt

$ \displaystyle\sum_{p=2}^P\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^p = \sum_{n=2}^N\sum_{p=2}^P\left( \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^p$

$ \displaystyle\sum_{p=2}^P\left( \dfrac{1}{n} \right)^p = \dfrac{1}{n}\left (\dfrac{1-(\frac{1}{n})^P}{1-\frac{1}{n}} \right) - \dfrac{1}{n} $

so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^N \left( \dfrac{1-(\frac{1}{n})^P}{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{n} \right) = \sum_{n=2}^N \left( \dfrac{1}{n-1} - \dfrac{1}{n} \right) - \sum_{n=2}^N\dfrac{(\frac{1}{n})^P}{n-1} $

so we have $ 1-1/N-\dfrac{N}{N^P}< 1 - 1/N - \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^N \dfrac{(\frac{1}{n})^P}{n-1} < 1 - 1/N $

Now I can see $ \dfrac{N}{N^P} $ goes to zero, but how would I prove it? also, by the sandiwch theorem it's obvious the sum converges to 1 - but how would I conclude to include H as the question states i.e. how would I choose H?